# Scala Play Reverse Routing: How do I redirect to to a POST route

Tags: scala, playframework

Doing a Redirect() always does a GET request, but the route im trying to redirect to is a POST route. It must also preserve the request data

Comment: this is a rare case for me.
user sends POST, i need to audit and log some things, then redirect the usual flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to audit and log some things, then redirect the usual flow

I can see where you are going with this, but I would suggest that [Action Composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition) would be a better approach. That way, you can have a reusable, testable, focused piece of code that just does your auditing and logging.

For example: (completely untested):

```
import play.api.mvc._

object AuditAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
      Logger.info("Action is being audited")
      YourAuditingLoggerHere.logAudit(request)
      block(request)
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
def submitAuditiableThing = AuditAction { implicit request =>
  YourBusinessLogicHere()
  Ok(views.html.success)
}
```